# How to remove title color box in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, html, charts

I am using chart js ( https://www.chartjs.org/ ) for charts. I checked all option in document but did not find how to hide title color box. Please see attached image

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Adding the following should hide the legend (I hope by  title color box you mean legend):

```
legend:
{
    display: false
}
```

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myChart');
var data = {
  labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
  datasets: [{
    label: "My First dataset",
    fill: false,
    lineTension: 0.1,
    backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,0.4)",
    borderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
    borderCapStyle: 'butt',
    borderDash: [],
    borderDashOffset: 0.0,
    borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
    pointBorderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
    pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
    pointBorderWidth: 1,
    pointHoverRadius: 5,
    pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
    pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
    pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
    pointRadius: 5,
    pointHitRadius: 10,
    data: [65, 59, 80, 0, 56, 55, 40],
  }]
};

function adddata() {
  myLineChart.data.datasets[0].data[7] = 60;
  myLineChart.data.labels[7] = "Newly Added";
  myLineChart.update();
}

var option = {
  showLines: true,
  legend: {
    display: false
  }
};
var myLineChart = Chart.Line(canvas, {
  data: data,
  options: option
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="250"></canvas>
<input type="button" value="Add Data" onclick="adddata()">
```

Comment: Now, this prop need to set inside options -> plugins -> legent -> display

Answer (score 15):

Extending [Peadar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56846386/4957508) with the options and plugins sections:

```
type: 'bar',
data: data,
options: {
    plugins: {
        legend: {
            display: false,
         } } }
```

Comment: Check this link to find how to write a good answer at Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer.

Comment: the title on my chart.js chart has been hidden/disabled perfectly. thank you. `[+1]`

Answer (score 4):

That box is the legend. You can turn it off via the legend flag: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    legend: {
      display: false
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
type: 'bar',
data: data,
options: {
    plugins: {
        legend: {
            display: false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 0):

For [vue-chartjs](https://vue-chartjs.org/), I added this in the `options` object

```
options: {
  legend: {
    display: false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me
options:{ { plugins: { legend: { display: false } } } }

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).